# Density Function of a Random Variable $X_2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ be the random variable that chooses a number $x$ from $(0,1)$ and let $X_2$ be the random variable that chooses a number $y$ from $(-x,x)$.

I've managed to find the density function of $X_1$ and conditional density function of $X_2$ given $X_1 = x$ but I couldn't find a way go get the density function of $X_2$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to find $\mathbb P(X_2 \le y)$ both for $-1 \le y <0$ and for $0 < y \le 1$ (for $y=0$ it is obviously $\frac12$ which you can use as a check on your other calculations).  Then take the derivative with respect to $y$ to get the pdf

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $X_2$ is a uniform variable as well. In general the pdf of a uniformly distributed variable is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{b - a} & \mathrm{for}\ a < x < b, \\[8pt]
  0 & \mathrm{elsewhere}
  \end{cases}$$

Thus the pdf of $X_2$ is

$$f_{X_2}(x_2)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{x- (- x)} & \mathrm{for}\ -x < x_2 < x, \\[8pt]
  0 & \mathrm{elsewhere}
  \end{cases}$$

Next you can use the transformation formula in order to obtain the pdf of $X_2$.

$$f_{X_2}(x_2)=\left|\frac{dg^{-1}(x_2)}{dx_2} \right|\cdot f_X(g^{-1}(x_2)),$$

where $g^{-1}(x_2)=\frac1{2x_2}$

Comment: $X_2$ may have a uniform distribution conditioned on $X_1$, but its marginal distribution is clearly concentrated around $0$.  It is not obvious to me that your pdf for $X_2$ would be zero at $x_2=\pm1$ as it should be

Comment: @Henry Thanks. I've made an edit.

Comment: I suspect you also have a problem with $g^{-1}(x_2)$ if $g(x_2)=\frac{1}{x_1-(-x_1)}=\frac{1}{2x_1}$ not  $=\frac{1}{2x_2}$ since constant functions do not have inverses.

Comment: Good point. I don't know how regard it.